# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mariadb

Boa tarde Pessoal, eu estou tentando criar uma tabela usando o Hibernate no Java, o banco de dados usado é o MariaDB, porém ao compilar a minha classe Java ocorre esse erro abaixo. Eu já verifiquei a class persistence.xml e coloquei na linha correta a senha, alguém pode me ajudar?

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ‘root’@‘localhost’ (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
… 29 more

Comment: Verifique também se o usuário e senha estão corretos.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, eu conseguir resolver o problema. Devido existir 2 SGBD instalado no meu notebook, ao instalar o SGBD MariaDB ele solicitou para alterar a porta TCP, por padrão é a 3306 instalada, eu alterei para a seguinte 3307 e faltou inserir na linha de url do banco no localhost a porta TCP no arquivo persistence.xml.

< property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/alura_jpa" />